# Z-index Not Working On Absolute-Positioned Element (despite having opacity, etc. removed)

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

Having read [this](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) after struggling with an absolute-positioned sub-menu that will not appear above page content on desktop breakpoints, I stripped all offending CSS identified in the article, but to no avail. The sub-menu in the below HTML will not appear above page content, despite having absolute position with z-index applied. Anyone with further thoughts on the issue, please let me know -- I'm baffled.

```
<nav id="nav-main" role="navigation">
  <ul class="site-nav site-nav__main">
    <li class="nav__menuitem nav__menuitem--main first level1"><a class="nav__menulink nav__menulink--main transition" href="my-link">my-link</a></li>
    <li id="subNav__parent" class="nav__menuitem nav__menuitem--parent transition clearfix level1">SubNav Toggle Label<span class="subNav__toggle">+</span>
      <ul class="subNav">
        <li class="nav__menuitem nav__menuitem--subnav first level2">
          <a class="nav__menulink nav__menulink--main transition" href="my-link2">my-link2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__menuitem nav__menuitem--subnav last level2">
          <a class="nav__menulink nav__menulink--main transition" href="my-link3">my-link3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

.site-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: .2s ease-out; /*related to a different transition; not relevant to the issue being 
    posted about*/
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

// SUBNAV

.nav__menuitem--parent { /*this is the click element used to open / close the sub-menu
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.subNav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  width: 250px;
  visibility: 0;
}

.subNav.open {
  transition-property: visibility, max-height;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height */
  visibility: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have `// SUBNAV` in your CSS because that's invalid CSS comment syntax and could affect the result

Comment: The CSS is produced using SCSS, where that format works. I included the comment simply to delineate between the CSS targets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When specifying position: absolute; the item will be positioned relative to its parent. You need to specifiy top:0 or similar to override this.

Here is a quick fiddle to illustrate

```css
.parent-nav {
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}

.sub-nav-parent {
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
}

/* 10px below sub nav parent */
.sub-nav-child {
  background-color:cyan;
  position:absolute;
  top:10;
  left:0;
  z-index:99;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
<h1>
  This is my page content
</h1>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
<p>Page body page body</p>
</div>

<div class="parent-nav">
<ul class="sub-nav-parent">
  <li>Sub Nav Parent</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-nav-child">
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not think this addresses the issue. To be clear, when the open state is active, the menu appears where it should relative to its parent, and is visible. The stacking issue relates to page content that appears later in the html.

Comment: If that is the case, then the content later must have a higher z-index if I am understanding you correctly. I've updated the snippet to illustrate that the nav is over the page body div

Comment: Yes that would make sense, but it didn't - there was no z-index applied to the wrapper for page content, which is what comes after the header in the html. As mentioned in the solution I posted, I wound up moving the header up in the stack order. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented doesn't address the fact that the HTML and CSS as written should work but doesn't, but FWIW, I z-indexed the header element and positioned it above the wrapping element for page content. Since the submenu is a child of the global nav, which in turn is a child of the header element, it's stack order is equivalent to the header's per the z-index default value of auto.